# Creating a single "view" button method for gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm just trying to create a single button "view" click for the data in the specific row for gridview and pass it to a Silverlight viewer.
Here's a "viewall" button I'm trying to figure out off of.

```
protected void btnViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["id"];
#if DEBUG
        if (id == null)
            id = "111"; // Use my own id for testing locally
#endif
        using (aDataContext dc = new aDataContext())
        {
            var query = (from a in dc.aLists
                         where a.ID == id
                         select new
                         {
                             a.aNumber,
                             a.bNumber,
                             a.cNumber,
                             a.dNumber,
                         }
                             );

            List<aListItem> List = new List<aListItem>();
            foreach (var queryItem in query)
            {
                aList.Add(new aListItem()
                {
                    aNumber = queryItem.aNumber,
                    bNumber = queryItem.bNumber,
                    cNumber = queryItem.cNumber,
                    dNumber = queryItem.dNumber
                });
            }
            Session["aList"] = aList;
        }
        Session["Database"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Viewer.aspx" + "?UseList=true");
    }
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Is it to insert the button in the GridView? Or to open the viewer window (or redirect to it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
It can be done with a `ButtonField` in the GridView:

Add the row-specific info to the `DataKeyNames` of the GridView (e.g. if the fields "name1" and "age2" of your data source are needed to view with your Silverlight viewer):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvClients" DataKeyNames="name1,age2" ... >
```

Add a ButtonField to the GridView:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="View" Text="View" />
```

Set the RowCommand event handler (can be done in markup or in code):

```
gvClients.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(gvClients_RowCommand);
```

And process the command:

```
void gvClients_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    string name1 = (string)gvClients.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["name1"];
    int age2 = (int)gvClients.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["age2"];

    // Open docName with the viewer
    ...
}
```

**Solution 2:** An alternative, which avoids a postback, would be to use a a HyperLinkField:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="View" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Viewer.aspx?Name={0}&Age={1}" DataNavigateUrlFields="name1,age2" />
```